# Selenium RDP + Java Service Wrapper

Tags: selenium, remote-desktop, selenium-grid, java-service-wrapper

I have a small issue with my current selenium setup.

I'm running selenium node and hub as a service using Java Service Wrapper.
At the moment to keep things simple I have only a single node.

When I run my tests, they aren't always stable and the screenshots come out black!
I'm logged into the machine using remote desktop but no window is opened when running the tests.

I am using Selenium 2.42.1 with IEDriver version 2.42.0 and the tests are running on a windows server 2012 machine.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going wrong! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get past the issue but still needs a better solution.

I had to start up a selenium node under the specific user that was logged in rather than using the node that had started up using the java wrapper service.